# Not recognizing new distance_threshold parameter for agglomerative clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The Scikit package doesn't seem to recognize the distance threshold parameter which I am trying to use instead of the n-clusters parameter because I don't know how many clusters I will end up with, it depends on the data.

I am wondering if this is because the distance_threshold parameter was rolled out relatively recently, but I import scikit at the top of the file so I don't see why this would be a problem. Everything works as long as I don't include this parameter.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward', 
distance_threshold = 400.0)  #the last bit here is the problem
cluster.fit_predict(Revs) 
labels = np.array(cluster.labels_).tolist()
```

It should run the clustering, instead I get this error message:

```
**TypeError**: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'distance_threshold'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distance_threshold` parameter a new addition in the latest version of sci-kit learn.

> New in version 0.21.

Make sure that you library is updated to the latest version. This error is mostly because you are using an older version.

You can check the version as below

```py
import sklearn

# Check version
print(sklearn.__version__)
0.21.
```

It wil display the version of your sci-kit learn library. To use `distance_threshold` parameter, the version must be 0.21.

Comment: You were correct, I was not running the 21.0 version of sklearn. However, I am running this in Jupyter, and the Jupyter terminal command: $ conda update scikit-learn failed to update me to the 21.0 version. Do you have any suggestions for getting the latest version on Jupyter?

Comment: Yes there is an issue with updating sklearn. First remove it completely and then install it again this time specifying the version as well. Try `conda remove scikit-learn` and then install again.